# Problem with displaying questions in documentclass{exam}

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins

I need to write the questions in Essay style on the second page my file. I use `documentclass{exam}`for this. But the bottom of the  second page I have a high and I do not know why. At the beginning I have configured `\usepackage[top=.4in, bottom=.1in, left=1in, right=.4in]{geometry}` - it is function for first page but on other no. Questions are unnecessarily on several pages.

```
    \documentclass{exam}  

\usepackage[top=.4in, bottom=.1in, left=1in, right=.4in]{geometry} 
\textheight=6in      
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{light}{rgb}{0,1,0.4}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Large OMR answer sheet for Test}
\end{center}

\begin{flushleft}
    \Large Date: 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c||c|c|c|c|} \hline 
        & & & & & & & & \hline 
    \end{tabular} \\
        \vspace{.5em}
    \Large Number of ID: 
\end{flushleft}
\tikzstyle{green}=[fill=green!60]
\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\sffamily},x=2cm] 
    \foreach \c in {1,2,3} {
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\c*4 cm] 
            \begin{scope}[yshift=-12,xshift=3.2]
                \foreach \digit in {0,2,4,6,8} { 
                    \begin{scope}[yshift=-.6*\digit cm]   
                        \foreach \count/\desc in {1/0, 2/0, 3/0, 4/0, 5/0} { 
                            \node[green,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at ({\count * 0.33},-.05) {\digit};

                            }
                            \end{scope}
                            \foreach \digit in {1,3,5,7,9} { 
                    \begin{scope}[yshift=-.6*\digit cm]   
                        \foreach \count/\desc in {1/0, 2/0, 3/0, 4/0, 5/0} { 
                            \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at ({\count * 0.33},-.05) {\digit};
                        }
                    \end{scope}
            } 
            }
        \end{scope}
            \draw (.15,-.25) rectangle(1.95,-6.15); 
    \end{scope} 
        } 
\end{tikzpicture}  
    \vspace{.4em}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{light}
{INSTRUCTIONS}  \\ 
    \hline
1.  Use HB pencil only this sheet.  \\
    \rowcolor{light}
2.  Darken the ovals fully.  \\
3.  Erase completely to change responses.  \\
    \rowcolor{light}
4.  Do not make any stray marks on this sheet.  \\ 
    \hline    
\end{tabular}
    \vspace{.5em}
        \hrule 

\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\sffamily},overlay]
    \foreach \col in {0,1,...,4} {
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\col*3.2 cm]
            \foreach \line in {1,2,...,20} { 
                \begin{scope}[yshift=-.7*\line cm]
                    \pgfmathparse{int(Mod(\line,2))?"green!60":"white"} 
                    \edef\filler{\pgfmathresult}
                    \draw [fill=\filler] (-.22,-.35) rectangle(2.8cm,.7em);
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\q{(10*\col)+\line}
                    \node at (0,-.05) {\normalsize{\q}}; 
                        \foreach \count/\desc in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} { 
                            \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at ({\count * 0.5},-.05) {\desc}; 
                        }
             \end{scope}
          } 
     \end{scope} 
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

    \newpage

    \pagenumbering{gobble} 

\begin{center}
\Large \textbf{Essay questions}
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
\pointsinmargin
\marginpointname{\%}
\pointformat{\slshape (\themarginpoints)}

\question[20] What is the Cost-benefit analysis?
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe the communication mechanisms.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe the definition of project work.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe the communication mechanisms.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] What is most important in the planning of communication?
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] What are the inputs and outputs in the assessment process?
\makeemptybox{2in}
\question[10] Describe COCOMO II.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe Inductive planning.
\fillwithlines{1.5in}
\question[5] Describe degree of delegation.
\fillwithlines{2in}
\question[5] What is the difference between leadership and management?
\fillwithlines{1in}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) An empty tabular to input the date seems overkill, doesn't `_ _ / _ _ / _ _ _ _` (with the `_` escaped as `\_`) do the job?  Could you double check that the code you've posted compiles (copying the question I get a number of errors.  Similarly, if you can be sure that your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is truly minimal insofar as everything in it is necessary to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the bottom margin right before the Essay questions the questions fit the page nicely. (They all fit in 2 pages)

Code (Starting after `\pagenumbering{gobble}`):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newgeometry{bottom=0.1cm}  %NEW
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\Large \textbf{Essay questions}
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
\pointsinmargin
\marginpointname{\%}
\pointformat{\slshape (\themarginpoints)}


\question[20] What is the Cost-benefit analysis?
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe the communication mechanisms.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe the definition of project work.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe the communication mechanisms.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] What is most important in the planning of communication?
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] What are the inputs and outputs in the assessment process?
\makeemptybox{2in}
\question[10] Describe COCOMO II.
\fillwithlines{1in}
\question[10] Describe Inductive planning.
\fillwithlines{1.5in}
\question[5] Describe degree of delegation.
\fillwithlines{2in}
\question[5] What is the difference between leadership and management?
\fillwithlines{1in}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```